# Substring error when string ends with ";" or " "

Tags: c#

Writing a function to take strings in the form of lines of code for a compiler and whenever I input a string that ends with a space or semicolon (as each line of code is meant to in my language) i get the following error on line 3:

> System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException was unhandled
>
> Index and length must refer to a location within the string.

I always receive this error if I am at the last ";" or " " of a string. For instance if i input "a = b;" it will read the a = b part and put them into my symbol table and recognise the delimiter "=" but give me an error once it reaches the ";". If I input "a = b" (with no semicolon) it will give the error after the second " " and not read the "b" at all. If I input 2 lines of code "a = b;" and "c = 1;" it will only give the error after the second line of code.

```
private static void readChar(
    ref int IX, ref string sentence, ref string testChar, ref int inputType)
{
    testChar = sentence.Substring(IX, 1);
    IX++;
    int IX2 = 0;
    int IX3 = 0;

    if ("|*/+-@#$%^&(),`=".Contains(testChar)) 
    {
        inputType = 5;
    } // delimiter

    else if (Char.IsDigit(testChar, IX2)) 
    {
        inputType = 3;
        IX2++;
    } // numeric          

    else if (Char.IsWhiteSpace(testChar, IX3)) 
    {
        inputType = 6;
        IX3++;
     } // space

    else if (testChar == ";") 
    {
        inputType = 7;
    } // semicolon          
    else 
    {
        inputType = 1;
    } // end alpha
}
```

Example code that calls readChar:

```
switch (inputType)
            {
                case 1: // alpha
                    {
                        convertCharToInt(ref inputChar, ref X);
                        wordTotal = wordTotal + X;
                        word = word + inputChar;
                        readChar(ref sentenceIX, ref sentence, ref inputChar, ref inputType);

                        while ((inputType != inputBreakChar) & (inputType != inputDelimeter) & (inputType != inputSemiColon)) //(inputType == 1)
                        {
                            convertCharToInt(ref inputChar, ref X);
                            wordTotal = wordTotal + X;
                            word = word + inputChar;
                            readChar(ref sentenceIX, ref sentence, ref inputChar, ref inputType);
                        } // end while inputType

                        calcSymbolTableIX(ref symbolTable, ref wordTotal, ref  R);
                        setSymbolTableIX(ref symbolTable, ref symbolTableName, ref word, ref R);

                        word = "";
                        break;
                    } // end case 1
```

Comment: If you want to write a parser, consider using a parser generator toolkit (GOLD Parser, ANTLR, etc.).

Comment: Can you show the code that calls readChar?

Comment: Sure, can do. Using this code from a template our lecturer gave us, haven't been programming for a few years as I was working in the networking field and the course I'm doing now just throws us into the deep end and wants us to develop a compiler for our own programming language. I think using a parsing generator toolkit will not be allowed for the course. Edited in some of the calling code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can add a check if this is the end of string by

```
if(IX == sentence.Length - 1 )
   testChar = sentence.Substring(IX);
else if(IX < sentence.Length - 1)
   testChar = sentence.Substring(IX, 1);
```

Comment: This is not going to solve the issue, because this does exactly the same thing as before. As soon as `IX` is `>= sentence.Length` your code will also throw.

Comment: Your edit made it even worse, because now you don't change `testChar` when `IX >= sentence.Length` so it will keep its previous value (it is passed into the method as `ref`). The problem is not this call - it is the missing/wrong abort condition which the poster has not shown.

Answer (score 0):

You need to show your break condition; as soon as `IX` reaches the last character you'll get the said exception if you try one more character at that time. Since the index is 0-based, your loop (which I assume you have) must stop as soon as `IX == sentence.Length`, and not only when it is greater.

Aside of this, your calls to `Char.IsDigit` and `Char.IsWhitespace` are broken, you need to pass `0` as the second argument instead of `IX2` or `IX3`.